# how to write a shell command to execute a command in an ALREADY open terminal window

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I have a process that depends on the internet, which dies randomly due to a spotty connection.

I am writing a cron script, so that it checks every minute if the process is running, and restarts it...

the process doesn't kill the terminal window it's in.

I don't want to kill the terminal - then spawn a new one.

I want the shell script I'm writing to execute in the window that's already open...

I'm using i3-sensible-terminal right now, but any terminal would do.

```sh
if ! ps -a | grep x123abc > /dev/null ; then
$CMD
fi
```

I have not yet located the information I need to have that run in a specific terminal.

changing the CMD to include a terminal seems to only open up a new window...

Comment: This is adding a lot of fragility and security exposure for no obvious purpose. A background process doesn't need to be in _any_ terminal at all; the better-practice approach is to let your operating system's process supervisor be responsible for running services (relevant aside: on a modern distro, the replacement for cron is systemd timers, which periodically kick off oneshot services); you can retrieve the logs from a service via journalctl to dump them to a terminal whenever you want, even if the terminal wasn't running at all when the service invocation took place.

Comment: (when I talk about "security exposure", part of the context for that is that a process needs to run as root to be able to connect to someone else's TTY; it's easier to run things unprivileged -- ideally, as a user that doesn't even have enough privileges to interact with your GUI environment at all -- when you need less magic).

Comment: ...now, _is it possible_ to write something that meets your requirements? Yes, absolutely, plenty of ways to do it; you could keep a symlink that points to your most-recently-opened TTY and have your `.profile` or similar update it; you could scan procfs and find open terminals; you could have your background tasks run in screen or tmux sessions and your interactive graphical terminals connect to them; you could use named FIFOs for I/O and attach to them from both background and foreground processes; you could do any number of things, but all of those things are generally adding moving parts

Comment: ...and systems with more moving parts are, in general, worse than simpler systems that don't require them.

Comment: use `grep -q ...` instead of `grep ... >/dev/null`

Comment: I agree with Charles: the process should log to a file. Use logrotate to archive old logs. Then in the terminal window you can do `less --follow-name +GF /path/to/logfile`

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting a different design to separate running your script from observing your script output.

1. Write script named `worker` "that depends on the internet, which dies randomly due to a spotty connection." appends **ALL** its output to log file `\home\$USER\worker.log`.
   Or just redirect **ALL** output from script named `worker` to log file `\home\$USER\worker.log`.

   ```
   worker > \home\$USER\worker.log 2>&1
   ```
2. Run script name `worker` as a restartable service with `systemd` unit service.

Here is a good article explaining this practice: https://dev.to/setevoy/linux-systemd-unit-files-edit-restart-on-failure-and-email-notifications-5h3k

3. Continue to observe the log file `\home\$USER\worker.log` using `tailf` command

   ```
   tailf \home\$USER\worker.log
   ```